# Subgroups in $Q_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I am finding particular subgroups of $Q_{12}$ and had a couple of questions about it.

$Q_{12}=\langle a,b:a^6=1,b^2=a^3,ba=a^{-1}b\rangle$

Firstly here is part of a solution I came across:

The first step is to establish the orders of the elements. So $1$ has order 1, $a^3$ has order 2, $a^2$ and $a^4$ have order 3, $a^ib$ has order 4 for all $i$, and $a$ and $a^{−1}$ have order 6. Therefore there is a unique subgroup of order 1, namely {1}, a unique subgroup of order 2, namely $\langle a^3 \rangle$ and
a unique subgroup of order 3, namely $\langle a^2\rangle$

How are the subgroups $\langle a^3 \rangle$ and $\langle a^2 \rangle$ identified straight away as unique? I understand that the fact that they are unique means they are normal and the fact they are normal means they are unique. But I wanted to know why they are identified as unique first hand in this example which then goes on to say because they are unique they are normal (I'm not interested in the other way round). Is it because they are cyclic?

Also the subgroups of order 4 are $\langle b \rangle$, $\langle ab \rangle$ and $\langle a^2b \rangle$. I'm struggling to see how because take $\langle b \rangle$, are the elements $\{1,b,a^3b\}$? but I thought a subgroup of order 4 had to have 4 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that all groups of prime order are cyclic and isomorphic to $Z_p$. Choose any other subgroup of order $2$ or $3$ it will be isomorphic to $Z_2$ or $Z_3$ (unique up to isomorphism), now by comparing order of elements of $Q_{12}$ you have the unicity. In your second question you forgot to put $a^3$ as an element of subgroup generating by $b$.

Comment: Okay thank you. Why can't say $b$ and $a^2b$ be in the same subgroup?

Comment: They can be in the same subgroup. For example, they are both in $Q_{12}$ which is a subgroup. If you mean, why don't they generate the same subgroup, you can see that by noticing that $a^2b$ is not in the list of elements of $\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: @harry55: Note that $$a^2b=(a^3a^{-1})b=a^3(a^{-1}b)=a^3(ba)=(a^3)ba=(b^2)ba=(b^2b)a=(b^3)a=a.$$ I just use some of the identities in $Q_{12}$. This means that $a^2b=a$. So any subgroup of $Q_{12}$ containing these two elements must be exactly $Q_{12}$ not a proper subgroup of $Q_{12}$ as $a$ and $b$ are generators of $Q_{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question: Being a normal subgroup and being a unique subgroup of a given order are in general not the same! A unique subgroup of a given order is always normal (and characteristic), but not the other way round.

The two are equivalent in the case of Sylow subgroups, such as the subgroup of order 3 in this example. But for example a Klein four-group has 3 subgroups of order 2, each normal since the group is Abelian.

Every subgroup of prime order is cyclic and hence generated by an element of the same order. Since there is just one element of order 2, namely $a^3$, the only subgroup of order 2 must be $\langle a^3 \rangle$.

Similarly a subgroup of order 3 is generated by an element of order 3. There are two such elements, $a$ and $a^{-1}$, but they generate the same group of order 3, hence it is unique.